# Change Value of a Dynamically Created Text Box when button is clicked C#

Tags: c#

I have dynamically created a button using a function I made which is meant to increase the value of another button created using a similar function. I'm able to retrieve the name of the dynamically created textbox, but since it is dynamically created, I can't reference it.

I've tried to pass the textbox through as a parameter, but it doesn't appear that I'm able to pass extra parameters:

```
Button ButtonDecreaseValue= addButton(ItemName, "-"); 

TextBox TextBoxItemAmount = addTextBox(ItemName, "0");
```

So, **how would I change the value of textbox one when `ButtonRemoveItem` is clicked?**

I've created an event handler for the button, like so:

```
ButtonIncreaseValue.Click += new EventHandler(ItemDecreased);
```

But, inside the event handler, I'm unsure how I would change the textbox name.

```
private void ItemDecreased(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button currentItem = (Button)sender;
    int ItemNo = Convert.ToInt32(currentItem.Tag);
    DataRow ItemInfo = getItemDetails(ItemNo);

    ItemInfo[0].ToString();
}
```

When clicking the button, the corresponding textbox should decrease in value.

Comment: Well, currently you're storing an integer in the Tag property.  Why not store there **both** the integer and a reference to the associated TextBox inside a [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2?view=netframework-4.8) (or a custom class, even)?  Then you can use the same procedure to extract both the integer and the textbox and do what you need to do...

Comment: yea storing the integer as a tag did become a problem so instead i just got the substring of the button name which is something like ItemNameButton and did a SQL search for the itemInfo instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming this is Windows Forms**

You said you have the name of the `TextBox`? You should be able to find it with that.

```csharp
private void ItemDecreased(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string textBoxName = HoweverYouGetTheDynamicTextBoxName();

   // Assumptions:
   //   1. ItemDecreased is a method on a Form or a UserControl.
   //   2. There is only one TextBox with the given name in the Form or UserControl.
   //   3. The TextBox is added to the Form or UserControl's Controls property.
   TextBox tb = Controls.Find(textBoxName, true).OfType<TextBox>().SingleOrDefault();
   if (tb is null)
   {
       // Couldn't find the text box for some reason.
   }
   // tb references the dynamically created text box.
}
```

Comment: Thanks i was unaware that you could search for controls.

Have a great day and thanks again!